# I believe it's possible to live in this conditions. Is it?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, atmosphere, science-in-society

Not only humans, but other animals as well live in this environment, it's like a clone of our environment but isolated.

i don't know how to quote here, but this pressure that he said.

"Of course, if just below 1 atmosphere (say, 1 km above sea level), 50% oxygen should be tolerable indefinitely. – Alexander 12 hours ago"

50% oxygen 40% nitrogen 10% others gases

60% oxygen 30% nitrogen 10% others gases

And is it possible to have this atmosphere is some part of the earth even if it's improbable?

Comment: At normal atmospheric pressure, 50-60% oxygen will become toxic to humans with long term exposure.

Comment: but the pressure being different could humans live? i'm not talking about hours but maybe years?

Comment: Of course, if just below 1 atmosphere (say, 1 km above sea level), 50% oxygen should be tolerable indefinitely.

Comment: damn i already love this site!

Comment: "other gases" may be an issue, there are plenty of things that are bad for us at 1/5 or 1/6 the concentration of oxygen. What gases are you thinking of?

Comment: they are irrelevant for the matter, i only need the most important one, it's for a project.

Comment: Please define other gases and pressure ranges you want to consider. And for having it on Earth, remember that in lab every mix is possible, even if some are unstable. Please define desired conditions.

Comment: Unless you specify the pressure range and the other gases this question is unclear.

Comment: I agree with Mołot's and L.Dutch's comments above. Also, please note that we very often deal with non-human creatures. If you are interested in humans-as-we-know-them, then please specify that in the question.

Comment: and how about now?

Comment: Do note that the pressure at 1 km altitude isn't *significantly* different from that at ground level. http://www.pilotfriend.com/av_weather/meteo/atmos_wt.htm and https://www.mide.com/pages/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator agree nicely here; the latter claims that the pressure at 1000 m, based on a standard pressure of 101,325 Pa at sea level, would be about 89,900 Pa, or only an about 10% difference. // cc @Alexander

Comment: @Michael Kjörling - it appears that 50% Oxygen at 1 atm is near the lower border of toxicity level, so lowering the pressure just a little should bring us into safety.

Answer (score 2):

Healthy humans can breath air with above usual (20%) oxygen content for short durations, but it is very unhealthy. Divers [sometimes use gas bottles with *slightly* above average oxygen content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrox), because it reduces the risk of decompression sickness, but only for a few hours at most.

So you could survive in a 50% atmosphere for a few hours, but you would soon start to experience symptoms of [oxygen toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity).

On the other hand, [there are some people suffering from chronic illnesses which actually need an above-normal oxygen level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_therapy). People suffering from such illnesses might enjoy a better quality of life in this environment than they would otherwise.

> And is it possible to have this atmosphere is some part of the earth even if it's improbable?

Only when it's for a very short duration or in a closed system. When there is any connection to the outside world, the high-oxygen air would immediately mix with regular air.

Comment: So you are saying that if a person has Hypoxia, they could live in that environment? kinda?

Comment: @LuLiddell Only with *just the right amount* of Hypoxia.

Comment: since you are being so helpful... what about pressure? could it help to live there?

Comment: Humans can, in fact, survive quite well in a high-oxygen atmosphere, if it is at a lower pressure.  The Apollo spacecraft originally used a pure O2 atmosphere at 5 PSI (as had previous spacecraft), but that was changed after the Apollo 1 fire.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes and no. *In flight* Apollo still used 100% O2 at low pressure throughout the program (the way also Apollo 1 was envisioned to be flown). They did however stop using 100% O2 at high pressure during ground testing, because doing so drove the O2 partial pressure up way high, with all of the associated risks.

Answer (score 1):

**No we would not survive.**

Fun fact oxygen is both necessary and toxic to us. It's a reactive compound and in quantities like you mentioned a spark would be enough to set us on fire.

Sure it would possible to have this atmosphere, provided a photosynthetic organism could survive its effects.

Lookup [Oxygen Toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's too much oxygen. But swap out 20-30% of the oxygen with argon and you've got an even more exotic, but breathable, atmosphere.

Comment: Oxygen toxicity is more about the oxygen partial pressure than the percentage of oxygen in the mixture. If the *total* atmospheric pressure is, say, 400 millibar, then the partial pressure of O2 will be around 200-250 millibar in the OP's case; which is about the same as on Earth. Apollo used 100% O2 at a bit over 300 millibar (actually about 5 psi) during spaceflight with no known ill effects for up to two weeks or so. The ISS on the other hand and for other reasons, uses a [standard atmopshere](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5690/415), basically the same mixture and pressure as on ground.